# ADFS 3.0 Error Event ID 511 and 364 when using Web Application Proxy

Tags: claims-based-identity, adfs

We are trying to set up our Development environment and we are facing issue's when WAP comes in play with ADFS. Below is what we have so far.

Our ADFS Server is tied to Active Directory and is working fine with one of the Claims aware relying party we have.

But when we installed the Web Application Proxy for this ADFS server and published this Claims aware RP in the WAP the ADFS Challenge is no longer working. Below is the flow

1. I'm to reach the External Url of this published app
2. User is getting re-directed to the ADFS Challenge screen with Error on it.

When I went to the ADFS 3.0 event viewer, I see two errors with Event ID 511, 364.

**Few things to note-**
I'm using a certificate issued by our Internal CA for ADFS Server.
The published application in the WAP is using a certificate issued by our Internal CA. Does this certificate of this published app must be issued issued by public CA even though this is a dev. environment setup ?

**Error with Event ID 511-**

The incoming sign-in request is not allowed due to an invalid Federation Service configuration.

Request url: 
 /adfs/ls?version=1.0&action=signin&realm=urn'%'3AAppProxy'%'3Acom&appRealm= masked it on purpose&returnUrl=masked it on purpose&client-request-id= masked it on purpose

User Action:
 Examine the Federation Service configuration and take the following actions: 
  Verify that the sign-in request has all the required parameters and is formatted correctly. 
  Verify that a web application proxy relying party trust exists, is enabled, and has identifiers which match the sign-in request parameters. 
  Verify that the target relying party trust object exists, is published through the web application proxy, and has identifiers which match the sign-in request parameters.

**Error with Event ID 364-**

Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data

Protocol Name:

Relying Party:

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7009: The request was malformed or not valid. Contact your administrator for details.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.MSISHttp.MSISHttpProtocolHandler.ValidateSignInContext(MSISHttpSignInRequestContext msisContext, WrappedHttpListenerRequest request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.MSISHttp.MSISHttpProtocolHandler.CreateProtocolContext(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.GetProtocolHandler(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler& protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The root of this issue for me was having a host file entry on my dev machine that pointed my federation server domain name to a specific ADFS machine in our farm, rather than to the NLB IP of our Web Application Proxy farm.  So, ensure your federation server domain name is resolving to your Web Application Proxy machine(s).

I was led to this by a comment in the following forum,

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/593638-sharepoint-2013-web-application-proxy

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have made separate entries in the host file of the client machine for adfs and web proxy machine with their public IP.

> 10.x.x.3 adfs.contoso.com (in next line) 10.x.x.2 webproxy1.contoso.com

Then I changed both IP as same but pointing to different machines. For example if, the federation service name is 'adfs.contoso.com' and the web proxy machine name is webproxy1.contoso.com. I have created two entries with IP of web proxy as

> 10.x.x.2  adfs.contoso.com (in next line)
> 10.x.x.2  webproxy1.contoso.com (or external URL name declared in webproxy)

Creating an adfs server with its IP entry in the host file makes direct contact with the ADFS server on redirect, breaking the reverse proxy functionality here.

Hope this helps you.